# Why is the column in my SQL table still NULL after I executed an INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the statement:

```
INSERT INTO Import_LAND5 (acreage) SELECT acres FROM IMPORT_LAND4
```

The **acreage** column in **Import_LAND5** is still NULL after executing this statement. Also, once executed I get the message (**1000 rows affected**) as if the statement executed correctly, but it did not.

```
INSERT INTO Import_LAND5 (acreage) SELECT acres FROM IMPORT_LAND4


INSERT INTO Import_LAND5 (acreage) SELECT acres FROM IMPORT_LAND4
```

I would expect that the **acreage** column in the **Import_LAND5** table would be populated, instead it still says NULL.

Comment: The INSERT statement adds new rows to the table and does not UPDATE existing rows.

Comment: did you try to see what is the column in **import_land4** ? I see no updates but only inserts

Comment: There is no `UPDATE` statement in your question, making it unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I amended it. I meant "INSERT". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @forpas Can I use the "UPDATE" statement then to pull data from the Import_LAND4  table and put into the Import_LAND5 table?

Comment: What does executing just `SELECT acres FROM IMPORT_LAND4` return?

Comment: Are the 2 tables related?

Comment: @JoeStefanelli it queries a listing of the acres of all the properties (land) in our system.

Comment: @forpas No, they're not.

Comment: Then how will the values of acres from IMPORT_LAND4 update the existing rows of IMPORT_LAND5. Which value from IMPORT_LAND4 will update which row of IMPORT_LAND5?

Comment: @forpas I am working on a data migration project (my first time) and I am still learning SQL as I go. So I am a bit confused, also I am new to the terminologies as well. I'm trying my best.The values I need are the IMPORT_LAND4 (table) acres (column) and I need to input them into IMPORT_LAND5 (table) acreage (column).

Comment: Is the table IMPORT_LAND5 empty?

Comment: The acreage column in IMPORT_LAND5 states NULL. So yes, it is empty.

Comment: Could you provide sample data, for reproduce the problem?

Comment: If IMPORT_LAND5 is empty then the INSERT statement you execute should work unless there are other columns in the table defined as NOT NULL that need to be filled too.

Comment: Yes, there are other columns, but I am not working on those yet, and some will stay NULL until we get more information of what data is required for those other columns. I need to fill in the acreage column in IMPORT_LAND5 though, because we have that data available now. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: if there are other fields in the Import_LAND5 table which are marked as NOT NULL in the table design, then you will not be able to insert a row unless you also provide values for those fields in your INSERT statement. The INSERT statement would probably generate an error about that when you try to run it.

Comment: Look up the differenct between `INSERT` and `UPDATE`

Answer (score 0):

Your statement imports ALL data from IMPORT_LAND4 , also NULL values. Maybe you need to add a WHERE condition to your SELECT to skip NULL values.